# MongoDB - How to select only numeric strings / Check whether string is numeric in mongo-shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a collection where the fields are string but those strings can have a numeric value inside e.g.:

myObject: {
 examples: [
          {example: "words", ...},
          {example: "more words", ...},
          {example: "111", ...},
          {example: "4502", ...}
          ...
         ]
       ...
           }

How can I query "111" and "4502" and any other numeric values in string format?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a regular expression in your query object to do that:

```js
// Select docs where at least one examples element contains an example value
// that's made up only of digits.
db.test.find({'examples.example': /^\d+$/})
```