# simplify mongodb pymongo query

Tags: python, pymongo

I have the following query in pymongo:

```
query2 = {"$and": [{'eventMetadata.doc.DocId':{"$exists":True}},
                   {'eventMetadata.doc.DocId':{"$not":{"$regex": "-"}}}]
         }
```

This works.
Basically means that the indicated field exists AND that does not contain the regex "-" which basically means that it does not contain "-"
I would like to know if there is a better way to check if "-" is not in the desired result without regex and also how could I check that the record is a number.

The following does not work and I dont know why:

```
query3 = {'eventMetadata.doc.DocId': {"$isNumber":True}}
```

--> giving cero results even If I know there are a lot of fields consisting in just in numbers (no alpha characteres)

Answer (score 0):

- To avoid using RegEx, you could resort to `$indexOfCP`:
  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/
- `$isNumber` doesn't look at the field contents, but at the field type. Hence, in case of `string` BSON type it will return `False`. Please refer to this SO for how to select numeric fields only (basically using regex): [MongoDB - How to select only numeric strings / Check whether string is numeric in mongo-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618519/mongodb-how-to-select-only-numeric-strings-check-whether-string-is-numeric-i)